# Hatcher 2.2.31 Invoke Mayer-Vietoris to wedge sum.

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Use the Mayer-Vietoris sequence to show there are isomorphisms $\tilde H_n(X \vee Y) \approx \tilde{H}_n(X) \oplus \tilde H_n(Y)$ if the basepoints of $X$ and $Y$ that are identified in $X \vee Y$ are deformation retracts of neighborhoods $U \subset X$ and $V \subset Y$.

So for this one, I am thinking of writing $\tilde H_n(X \vee Y)$ in the form of $\tilde H_n((X \cup U) \cup (Y \cup V))$ in order to satisfy the Mayer-Vietoris sequence condition, that $X \vee Y$ is the union of interior of $X \cup U$ and $Y \cup V$. But I am not sure how to justify it?

Comment: Since $U \subset X$, we have $X \cup U = X$. What you want is $X \cup V$ and $Y \cup U$. Use the definition of the quotient topology to justify that both are open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost right except you've taken an essentially redundant union (of $X$ and $U$, and $Y$ and $V$). What you want to use as your two spaces is $W=X\cup V$ and $Z=Y\cup U$ which have intersection equal to $U\cap V$ which clearly deformation retracts first to $U$ (or $V$), and then to the wedge point. You can also see that $W$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$, and $Z$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y$.

Comment: Oh exactly! That's why I got stuck! Thank you so much Daniel!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help.

Comment: Just to make it clear: So the wedge point was on the boundary of $X$ and $Y$? I am not sure that why we can just chose $X$ and $Y$, but we need $W$ and $Z$.

Comment: Consider $X=Y=([0,1],1)$. You can't choose $X$ and $Y$ to be the spaces used in the application of Mayer-Vietoris because the interior of $X$ and the interior of $Y$ (seen as subset of their wedge sum) do not cover the wedge $X\vee Y=[0,1]\times\{0\}\sqcup [0,1]\times\{1\}/((1,0)\sim(1,1))$

Comment: I see. That is clear now. Thank you so much Daniel!

Comment: Although this was posted ages ago, do you mind explaining the intuition that might lead one to choosing these sets?

Comment: We've these types of questions, sometimes the easiest approach is to just look at the information provided and see what you can do with them. In this case, there are very few choices for what to take as your two spaces in terms of unions and intersections of the ones appearing in the question, and even fewer that give something useful when you take their intersection (in this case it was clear that $U \cap V$ is contractible, so we want that to appear somewhere). Of course, if you draw the picture of the above setup, it also makes it easier to see what spaces one might want to take.